# Silverlight DataForm doesn't display the correct initial value

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-5.0, dataform

I'm trying to force the DataForm to display an initial value that's different from the first of the ItemsSource list with no success.

I'm working with the MVVM patern.

I simply bind the ItemsSource to a Customers list (All customers), then bind CurrentItem to the one customer I want to be displayed as an initial item on the DataForm:

```
     <toolkit:DataForm Height="292"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
                    CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"
                    Margin="88,122,0,0"
                    Name="customerDataForm"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="342" />
```

And in the viewmodel I set:

```
  void loadOpCustomers_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Customers = _Context.Customers;
     SelectedCustomer = Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == initialCustomerID).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

When I debug it SelectedCustomer holds the exact customer I want, but the DataForm insists to show the first of the Customers list.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a binding mode in your XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And make sure your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged.